# Splitting string from inputstream with whitespace delimiter

Tags: c++

I can't seem to split my string with the whitespace delimiter.

I tried using the getline(cin, myString).

I input the string as "10 20 30", when I print the string onto the output stream, I get "20 30", but not the 10.

I also tried the while(cin >> string). It works here, but the while loops never terminates.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `istringstream`:

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
istringstream ss(str);

for(string word; ss >> word; )
    cout << word << endl;
```

Your `while(cin >> str);` doesn't stop unless:

1. Something fails in `>>` which is hard in your case.
2. EOF occurs (You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd> It depends on your system)
3. A user defined condition: `if(str.find('\n')) break;`

Comment: For loop is fired before even get a chance to enter input