# C++ stream iterators

Tags: c++, stream, iterator

I am trying to use the stream iterators to read and output words from the console. Here is my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> stringVec;

    copy(istream_iterator<string>(cin), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(stringVec));

    sort(stringVec.begin(), stringVec.end());

    unique_copy(stringVec.cbegin(), stringVec.cend(), ostream_iterator<string> (cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

When I input "this is it" and press Return in the console, the cursor there keeps on blinking (indicating that it's waiting for input).

Can anyone please offer some insights on my approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can use `getline` and `istringstream`. It reads a string until `\n` and then passes it to copy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

...

vector<string> stringVec;

string str;
getline(cin, str);
istringstream ss(str);

copy(istream_iterator<string>(ss),
     istream_iterator<string>(),
     back_inserter(stringVec));

sort(stringVec.begin(), stringVec.end());

unique_copy(stringVec.cbegin(),
            stringVec.cend(),
            ostream_iterator<string> (cout, "\n"));
```

*<sup>Two same questions in a day, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18941199/952747).</sup>*

Comment: I can't say you _have to_ use it, but it's an easy and standard way. Also you can replace `cin` with any custom stream.

Comment: Thanks. The above codes do not compile on my side.

VS said the following error:
IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "std::istream_iterator<_Ty, _Elem, _Traits, _Diff>::istream_iterator [with _Ty=std::string, _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Diff=ptrdiff_t]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (std::istringstream)"

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a EOF for `istream_iterator<string>()`, which constructs the end-of-stream iterator.

Use <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> or (<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> on linux ) to stop getting input from stream

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to provide EOF replacing istream_iterator<string>() ?  This is actually directly from the code from Nicolai's book (C++ Standard Library).

Comment: @Genius101 `istream_iterator<string>()` waits for an `EOF`, which is can be given with the above keys. Else you might want to add string into a vector using a loop.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I am using VS2012 in Windows. The above works on your side I suppose?

Comment: @Genius101 it should work, just press `Ctrl+Z` after you're done entering the text